# issue with joined report grouped by owner

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

**Data Model**

- the standard Opportunity object
- custom object called Objective

Both have an owner field.

**Problem**

Wanted to make a joined report as follows:

- Opportunities with Products as primary report type.
- Objectives as secondary report type

When adding the second report type, Salesforce told me (as I would expect) that the common fields would be from the "User" object.

The report however doesn't provide the results that I would expect.

As you can see, it either shows the record count on the left or on the right.
If I show the details, it seems that the 65 records that are on the right are not grouped according to the OWNER of those records but grouped by who created the record.

While in the left report type, the records are correctly grouped by the OWNER of the opportunities.

This seems very strange to me.

Any ideas on what could be the issue here?

[image: issue group by owner]

Comment: I suspect it's another case of "mutant fields" - Opportunities can be owned only by humans but  all custom objects have `OwnerId = (User, Queue)`. Can you try making custom field (on both?) called `Owner__c` and fill it in with same user for couple of records?

Comment: Ok, this is very strange to me. I tried as you said but no success. Salesforce still seemed to be using the created by of my custom object to do the join on instead of the owner. Now, I was thinking, maybe it is as you say that Salesforce is confused as to which lookup to the user it should take. I then tried by creating a custom report type where I only added the owner lookup to the user and didn't add the created by. At first, this seemed to be going in the good direction. I was able to join the 2 on user. But then... it doesn't allow me to save or run the report. (type set as deployed)

Comment: Interesting. What error message are you getting?

Comment: None. When I add the custom report type, the run report and save buttons are greyed out. If I build a fresh report based on this custom report type, I can save / run the report. As soon as I change the format to joined, the buttons are greyed out again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever attempt to create the joined report in the opposite order to see what happened? E.G. Objectives, then Opportunities with Products? I'd be curious to know if the connections were made when you tried your report that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating two custom report types, the first one is Users with Opportunities, the second one is Users with Objectives. Then you should be able to create a join report with the two new report types and join them with the User object.